# Change rendering order of objects in MapInfo table?

Tags: mapinfo, rendering, order

i have one big MapInfo file where i did a lot of digitizing work. Now i have the problem of disapearing points under polygons (or polygons under polygons, lines under polygons etc.).

How can i manipulate the order objects are rendered?

My solution so far is to create a couple of more physical layers and add objects to them when i want them "above" the main layer. I have to send the digitized map to a customer, i don't want to send her 4 files just to have the outlines of a park bench not dissapearing under the green "grass" polygon it is situated in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapInfo Pro uses the spatial index to fetch the records from a table when it needs to render them on a map. There is no way around this.

You can overrule the spatial index, if you create a query, sort the records and then add the query to the map. A query is rendered in the order the records appear in the query. This means you want the objects that should appear at the top, to be at the end of the query.

The solution really is to split your layer into multiple layers.

One layer with grass, another layer with park benches and so on.

I certain your customer would also prefer to have these different object types in different layers.

Comment: ok, so no work around as to work with different layers. i will sort the objects more thematically in future to avoid this problem :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could select all the points and lines in the table and cut them, after that just paste them back. Now the points and lines will be the last objects in a table (in other words on the top).

Or, select all the polygons and change the style - apply the style that uses a transparent fill or no fill at all.

Comment: i tried that (cutting and pasting it back in) but it did not change the rendering order - maybe because then the Object Index is also just copied and therefore it is still rendered at the same position as before?

changing the style might be an idea, but i consider it more as a last resort :/

Comment: That will only work until you zoom or pan, than Pro will render the objects again in a order determined by the spatial index.